# Using Bootstrap Component in Action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I use bootstrap icons in `@HTML.ActionLink`?
When I used this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Admin", new {@class = "glyphicon glyphicon-off" })
```

It shows this: bootstrap icon, but there is still text.  [image: This]

How do I remove "logout" and just show only the icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, it is easy and clean if you create hyperlink manually.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Admin")">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot pass an empty string as the `linkText` parameter of the `Html.ActionLink` helper method.

So write pure HTML to build an anchor tag and set the text as empty. You may use the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the url to your action method and use the result of that as the href value of the anchor tag.

This should work fine.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Admin")"  class= "glyphicon glyphicon-off"></a>
```

Comment: Show me This Error `Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: linkText`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new class to hide anchor texts, this way you can reuse this feature for all anchors by just adding class.

```
a.hide-text{
    line-height: 0; 
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent; 
 }
```

And

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Admin", new {@class = "hide-text glyphicon glyphicon-off" })
```